Singularity on RHEL-8: failed to connect to dbus
I am using Singularity on RHEL-8. I just upgraded to cgroupsv2 so that I could throttle resource usage. I also delegate CPU controller permissions in my /etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/override.conf as described here.
So far, so good. So I try to run: singularity run --cpus 0.8 container.sif.
I get the following error (some of the random strings randomized and shortened):

FATAL:   container creation failed: while applying cgroups config: while creating cgroup manager: failed to connect to dbus (hint: for rootless containers, maybe you need to install dbus-user-session package, see https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/master/docs/cgroup-v2.md): could not execute busctl --user --no-pager status (output: "Failed to get credentials: No such process\nBusAddress=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-4843,guid=35345\nBusScope=user\nBusID=343345\n"): exit status 1

Indeed, if I try busctl --user status, I get a connection refused error.
There are some related questions like this one and this one, but my dbus session seems to be running fine, and I am not trying to run this as root. What gives?

You need to reset some environment variables, restart d-bus, and reload the daemon:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
export $(dbus-launch)
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Then wait a minute for it to reload. Your busctl --user status should now succeed.
If you're anything like me, the next problem will be that the CPU access has not been delegated. If you look at /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control, it'll have everything except for cpu. And then when you try to modify the file (even with sudo), you'll have problems. The solution there is to sudo systemctl stop rtkit-daemon, then modify the file to add the word cpu, then restart sudo systemctl start rtkit-daemon. Your container command should now work.
